# Чистка памяти после закрытия iFrame

Tags: javascript, память, iframe

Как корректно закрыть/удалить iframe со страницы что бы память освободилась?

Заметил, что при открывании на основной странице других iframe-ов памяти потребляется все больше и больше, но при этом если просто удалить iframe, очистка памяти не произойдет.

Как быть?

Нашел [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128458/iframes-and-memory-management-in-javascript) способ.

Сотворил такой код (не судите строго, делал на скорую руку):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.purgeFrame = function() {
        let frame = $(this);
        frame.each(function () {
            let _frame = this;
            $(_frame.contentWindow).off();
            let doc = $(_frame.contentWindow.document);
            doc.find('*').off().remove();
            doc.off();
            doc.empty();
            $(_frame).remove();
        });
    };
})($);
```

После выполнения iframe пропадает, но памяти очищается все пару мб, тогда как занимало около 20.

Добрые люди, подскажите.

Comment: Ну там бери и проверяй утечки. В браузерах память сама уже давно не течёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy каким это образом? то что память растет я и так вижу в диспетчере хрома. Но это никак не решает проблему, от слова совсем.

Comment: Используйте вкладку "Memory" в инструментах, там увидите что течёт, куда и по кому :)

Comment: Там же и есть [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128458/iframes-and-memory-management-in-javascript). У меня работает

Comment: @NikitaSmith ну я же привел пример выше. не работает.

Comment: @Tsyklop, там есть record allocation profile, который показывает, какие именно объекты выжили.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну окей. а как их почистить тогда?

Comment: @Tsyklop, посмотреть, кто их удерживает и исправить код.

Comment: @Qwertiy посмотрел я туда. НО понять какой именно элемент из iframe трудно. Да там вообще понять трудно.

Comment: @Qwertiy буду благодарен за подсказку

Answer (score -1):

Запускайте перезагрузку контента перед удалением `iframe`:

```js
$('iframe')[0].contentWindow.onbeforeunload = function() {
  console.log("unloading iframe");
  console.log(this);
}
$('#cleanIFrame').click(function() {
  $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.location.reload();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('iframe').remove();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='cleanIFrame'>Удалить</button>
<br />
<iframe src="http://google.co.in" width="300" height="400" />
```

Comment: в чем особенность? я так пробовал и у меня не изменилось ничего.

Comment: у меня тут iframe не открывается. в консоли ошибка.

Comment: Попробовал этот способ. При вызове `.reload()` у фрейма у меня виснет вся страница.

Comment: @Tsyklop дай немного времени, пытаюсь сделать другой вариант на чистом js